# How is the decelerationRate used by UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm trying to replicate the scrolling and deceleration behavior of `UIScrollView`. Scrolling works nicely. I also calculate a scrollVelocity during scrolling (points per second). When the user lets go, I want to keep scrolling with this velocity and gradually come to a stop, just like `UIScrollView`.

I thought the obvious thing to do would be to keep multiplying the scrollVelocity with a decelerationRate like UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal (0.998). When I do this the deceleration is way to slow. It keeps on scrolling for ages. Of course I could just use a smaller value, but I'm trying to get the same effect and use the same values.

How else could `UIScrollView` use the decelerationRate constants like 0.998 to decrease the scrolling velocity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing Apple, I'd say they're using a Bezier path to calculate the scrollVelocity, and the `decelerationRate` affects the position of the second control point. The reason I believe that is because that's the way the [CAMediaTimingFunction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CAMediaTimingFunction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) works in core animation.

Comment: Could you elaborate? How would I use a bezier for scroll speed? Thanks!